# AbstractVehicle using Time as class member

Tags: java

I have made a class AbstractVehicle:

```
package TruckingCompany;

public abstract class AbstractVehicle implements Movable
{
public Location location;
public Time time;
double direction;
public final int speed;
public AbstractVehicle(int speed)
{
    if(speed<=0)
        speed=10;
    this.speed=speed;
}
public int getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}
public void setLocation(Location location)
{
    this.location=location;
}
public void setTime(Time time)
{
    this.time=time;
}
public Location getLocation()
{
    return location;
}
public Time getTime()
{
    return time;
}
public void pointTo(Location where)
{
    direction=location.getDirectionFrom(where);
}
public void move(Time until)
{
    double dx,dy;
    int howLong;
    howLong=time.compareTo(until);
    dx=Math.sin(direction)*howLong/60;
    dy=Math.cos(direction)*howLong/60;
    if(howLong>0)
    {
        time=new Time(until);
        location=new Location(location.getX()+dx,location.getY()+dy);
    }
}
public void move(double howFar)
{
    double dx,dy;
    dx=Math.sin(direction)*howFar;
    dy=Math.cos(direction)*howFar;
    location=new Location(location.getX()+dx,location.getY()+dy);
}
}
```

This is the interface Movable:

```
package TruckingCompany;

public interface Movable 
{
public int getSpeed();
public void setLocation(Location location);
public void setTime(Time time);
public Location getLocation();
public Time getTime();
public void pointTo(Location where);
public void move(Time until);
public void move(double howFar);
}
```

This is a constant problem for me in Java and in other OOP languages like C++ .
The problem is :

- Is correct to make the class AbstractVehicle HAVE an object of type Time?
- Could it inherit from Time?

In procedural programming like C I could write a program and all I had to worry about was efficience, and a acode that make his job.
But this case there are also conceptual errors, so there's a rule to know is what I'm doing is conceptually right? So for example someone could say that a Vehicle shouldn't have a Time object because all Vehicles can't have a different time.
But I fail to get the criteria: when to put the HAVE relationship instead of inheriting, or when to don't use at all HAVE relationship and just corrdinate that field frome xternal classes.
This case the Vehicle could not have an object of type Time, and could have just a method `move(double howLong)` indicating the minutes it had to move.I also could do it this way.
But why? And what's the criteria to choose?

Comment: When you look at a vehicle, what is a *time*? Your vehicle **has-a** time, but, honestly, I have no idea what (kind of time) it is.

Comment: It's a class I made: http://pastebin.com/XN0xvFjh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't inherit from `Time`. Your class `AbstractVehicle` is not a `Time`, it uses it. You don't want to allow all behavior of `Time` to be available in `AbstractVehicle`.

So your decision to make `AbstractVehicle` have `Time` is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

> Is correct to make the class AbstractVehicle HAVE an object of type Time?

Absolutely. This is called enhancing your class through composition and is to be encouraged.

> Could it inherit from Time?

Absolutely not since Time and Vehicle fail the "is-a" test -- a vehicle is not inherently a more specialized type of time as Dog is a more specialized type of Animal. On the other hand, you can allow the programmer to use more specialized children of Time by giving the class a `setTime(Time t)` "setter method" (as your AbstractVehicle class already employs). This is called "dependency injection" and also is a good thing.

> But I fail to get the criteria: when to put the HAVE relationship instead of inheriting, or when to don't use at all HAVE relationship and just corrdinate that field frome xternal classes.
>    This case the Vehicle could not have an object of type Time, and could have just a method move(double howLong) indicating the minutes it had to move.I also could do it this way. But why? And what's the criteria to choose?

I don't fully understand this part of your question. If someone else doesn't address it soon, could you clarify it a bit?

Comment: I mean that I don't get the criteria of how to decide between inheriting from a class, using that class or just nothing.For example I could inherit form Time, use Time, or just don't put anything.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many rules you need to memorize.  You learn how to OOD (Object Oriented Design) works by seeing good examples of well designed classes and by having other critique your design as you've done here.

Your classes are modeling a real thing here.  So, is Time a property of vehicle.  I doubt it.  Unless you meant timeInService or timeTraveling (wait, that means something else!). If time refers to some clock, then it is a property of your whole program, maybe of the client system, but not of vehicle.

The fields of AbstractVehicle are the properties you need you model to have.  Are your Vehicles always traveling at a constant speed and they never stop?  If not, then speed should not be final.  Maybe you can have a maxSpeed which is final, but I would think speed can change.

Comment: I imagined time like an internal clock of the vehicle, the speed is a maxSpeed (I'll change the name).
The vehicles can move only at that speed, or hold on in a fixed location.